# MVC Razor - Assigning an id to a button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

This is my ActionLink razor button:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete Partial", "DeletePartialView", new { id = item.ClubID }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-xs" })
```

How would I assign it an `id` of `deleteClub-opener` so that when it is clicked it calls this jQuery code:

```
$("#deleteClub-opener").click(function () {
    $("#DelteClub-dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already adding a `class` to the element via the `HtmlAttributes` property, you just need to add the required `id`:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Delete Partial", 
    "DeletePartialView", 
    new { id = item.ClubID }, 
    new { 
        @class = "btn btn-danger btn-xs",
        id = "deleteClub-opener" // <- add the id here
    })
```

Further information on [ActionLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: I think you need @id

Comment: Not in this case as `id` isn't a reserved keyword in C#